# What material should a mjolnir type weapon be made out of?

Tags: weapons, materials

In this [question](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/27907/how-would-a-weapon-act-if-it-negates-the-effects-of-gravity-for-itself) we came up with a weapon that would be quite powerful if it could have variable weight and inertia. In the comments of the accepted answer a user pointed out that we basically invented Mjolnir, Thor's hammer. And I agreed, it basically can do anything Mjolnir can except conjure lightning, you could even fly with it if you were <s>brave</s> stupid enough to actually throw the hammer while it is attached to you.

So in a Melee weapon that you can control the inertia and weight of, what type of material should it be made out of so it resists the potential huge impacts with other objects so it breaks the thing it is impacting without breaking itself? I feel like most common metals e.g. Iron, steal, aluminium, etc would be too weak.

The main concern would be a Hammer that is solid all the way through, though bonus points if you can have something fragile inside like electronics.

Comment: I can't help but think of X-men, and ponder if you've simply built a weapon by putting Juggernaut at the end of a stick.

Comment: LOL, reminds me of the franklinator from Futurama but on a much larger scale.

Comment: Well I'll be darned, I inspired a question. +1

Comment: My friends and I have a non-cannon theory about Mjolnir.  It's not heavy.  It's stubborn.  It doesn't dig a huge hole in the ground when you drop it, but it doesn't move after that.  I think it actually makes more sense than the canon rationale: Thor can't wield it because he's some superhero... Thor can wield it because he's the only person in the universe that's more stubborn than Mjolnir is!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Neutronium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neutronium).  Pure degenerate matter that is neutrons almost all the way through, plus whatever controls the apparent mass.  Given the incredible density of this stuff, bang it against a merely solid object and it'll smash through it almost as easily as it would pass through a gas.

It'll be approaching the strength of an atomic nucleus too, not weak like stuff that's mostly empty space filled with a relative handful of electrons.  Nothing other than more neutronium could be expected to have any significant effect on it.

You could have this weapon effectively empty space enclosed by a hair's thickness of neutronium 'foil' (as long as you can keep it stable using your 'electronics'), say 1 cubic millimetre of neutronium in total, and it'd *still* weigh *400,000 metric tons* if you weren't controlling the mass.

Put *this* Mjollnir down and turn off the mass controller, and from a standing start, it'd punch a hole all the way down to the centre of the earth from sheer ground pressure, and it'd oscillate around for some time, ripping up the earth's core until it eventually settled at earth's centre of mass.

Throw *this* with its mass turned down to zero, then, while still attached to it, restore its mass, and you'd be dragged about as far as you could throw anything, but no further - gravity provides a constant acceleration regardless of the mass of the lesser of the two masses, so it'd fall to earth just as soon as anything else you threw.  Of course, with negative mass, you could make a [diametrical drive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breakthrough_Propulsion_Physics_Program#Diametrical)

If you have a device that can control the effective mass of an object, you can then build a diametrical drive and an alcubierre warp drive ship, and given those, getting to a neutron star and ripping off a tiny fragment of neutronium wouldn't pose too much of a problem.

Comment: Well crap. "Mjolnir was forged in the heart of a dying star" is the description of if in the comics I think, that would be a Neutron star most likely, which would have Neutronium. Lol, nice work

Comment: Welp. Beat me to the punch. I was going to say whatever the heck they make those Keyblades out of, but those do still have some weight to them.

Comment: To be fair, when I made that comment, I really did mean variable inertia, as in the ability to arbitrarily designate the vector magnitude of the object. Which really would let you actually fly, even if it was while awkwardly holding onto a levitating doomsday device and flapping in the wind.

Comment: Neutronium doesn't work that way.  It's not a solid material, it's just what matter becomes when it is under sufficient gravitational pressure.  Remove a chunk of matter from a neutron star, and it will instantly evaporate into a puff of neutron gas once you leave.

Comment: @IndigoFenix that is quite likely,  hence my statement, "as long as you can keep it stable using your 'electronics'".

Comment: @MontyWild Positively-charged strangelets might work, but we don't know enough about strange matter to say how it would behave on macroscopic scales.

Answer (score 1):

If you can't control the inertia and mass (purely real-life physics), then I would recommend making the hammer out of aerogel coated with a few millimeters of maximum-strength steel similar to what the recent Tesla Cybertruck is made of. Put a slight flexible buffer material between the aerogel core and the steel to prevent breakage if the steel expands or contracts with temperature differences.

If you can control the inertia and weight: Forget neutron star matter, shape the head of the hammer from the core of a black hole. It should theoretically warp whatever it contacts into oblivion, although you need to keep a tight lid on its mass when you aren't actively using it.

Figuring out how to shape the core of a black hole into a hammer head is left as an exercise to the reader.

Figuring out how to fight with a black hole on the end of a hammer handle and not getting warped or time-dilated into oblivion is also left as an exercise to the reader.